# Spark SQL error cannot evaluate expression, worked in 2.3.2 and fails in 2.4

Tags: apache-spark

I just posted an issue, I hope I did not over-step the protocol!

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26777

I wonder if anyone has hit a problem with SQL Spark 2.4.0 (from Pyspark 3.6)

```
spark.sql("select partition_year_utc,partition_month_utc,partition_day_utc \
    from datalake_reporting.copy_of_leads_notification \
    where partition_year_utc = (select max(partition_year_utc) from datalake_reporting.copy_of_leads_notification) \
    and partition_month_utc = \
    (select max(partition_month_utc) from datalake_reporting.copy_of_leads_notification as m \
    where \
    m.partition_year_utc = (select max(partition_year_utc) from datalake_reporting.copy_of_leads_notification)) \
    and partition_day_utc = (select max(d.partition_day_utc) from datalake_reporting.copy_of_leads_notification as d \
    where d.partition_month_utc = \
    (select max(m1.partition_month_utc) from datalake_reporting.copy_of_leads_notification as m1 \
    where m1.partition_year_utc = \
    (select max(y.partition_year_utc) from datalake_reporting.copy_of_leads_notification as y) \
    ) \
    ) \
    order by 1 desc, 2 desc, 3 desc limit 1 ").show(1,False)
```

Above PySpark/SQL code works in Presto/Athena and it used to work in Spark 2.3.2 as well.

Now in the latest **Spark 2.4.0 AWS EMR 5.20.0** it fails with **error** (query syntax):

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   o1326.showString. : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot
>   evaluate expression: scalar-subquery#4495 []

I submitted an issue in Spark but I also wondering if someone knows about it already?

I could re-write this SQL code to break it up into multiple (3-4) simple SQL statements but thought to post it here for opinions as it is rather trivial code.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i'm running into the same issue and am reverting to EMR 5.17 for the time being but doing some reading and curious is subquery aliasing might be the cause.

"Un-aliased subquery’s semantic has not been well defined with confusing behaviors. Since Spark 2.3, we invalidate such confusing cases, for example: SELECT v.i from (SELECT i FROM v), Spark will throw an analysis exception in this case because users should not be able to use the qualifier inside a subquery. See SPARK-20690 and SPARK-21335 for more details."

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-migration-guide-upgrade.html

You're using `datalake_reporting.copy_of_leads_notification` in your query and subquery, maybe you need to use an alias?

Comment: thanks, just tried it, put aliases everywhere, same error. I broke up this query into 3 smaller queries which worked but it was a code change. It is a bug/regression, since it works in 2.3.x.

Comment: Here's the solution from the Spark team

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26996

" turn off `spark.sql.optimizer.metadataOnly` configuration". Can confirm this works @AcidRider